# safari extension with a custom sidebar

Tags: safari-extension

Do you know if it is possible to create a custom sidebar like the one for "show sidebar"?

I know you can create a popup view, but it hovers above the web page - I am looking for a native kind of view like the "sidebar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari does not support any native sidebar at the moment.

Chrome 114+ supports [sidePanel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/), Firefox and Opera support [sidebarAction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/sidebarAction). It's possible that in the future Safari may support `sidePanel` since it's a newer API, but I don't expect that to happen anytime soon.

Comment: Since new version of Chrome 114, Chrome supports too. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/whatsnew/#side-panel-launch